# How to use figures stored in variables as subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Assume a set of 4 *matplotlib* figures stored in variables **fig1** to **fig4**.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot([2, 2, 2, 2])

fig3 = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 3, 1, 4])

fig4 = plt.figure()
plt.plot([4, 3, 2, 1])

# code to create subplots using the fig1 to fig4 variables
# i.e. without recreating the original 4 plots
```

Using matplotlib (or maybe another package), how does one create a figure of subplots (such as the example below), with the subplots being **fig1** to **fig4**?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: One doesn't. Many similar questions exist, the quintessence being, that you can create functions to call with an axes as argument, which would either be the single axes of a figure, or one of the subplots of a figure.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
#Set First Axis
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.plot([1, 3, 1, 4])


#Set Second Axis
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.plot([2, 2, 2, 2])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax3.plot([1, 3, 1, 4])

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax4.plot([4, 3, 2, 1])
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this but you are not using the variables to create the subplot but rather recreating the figures from scratch.